# How does this site know that I am opening another tab?

Tags: html, session, browser, web

When I login to a site, which is a "learning system" at my university, I have found that I cannot open a new tab with the same site open. When I do so, somehow the site is aware and displays the following message?

[image: Session already running?]

How on earth does the site know what tabs I have open on my computer? As far as I know, the front-end code shouldn't have any access to my private browser information. What accessible information could this site be using to determine that I have another tab open already?

I am accessing the site using a private computer, and the site being accessed isn't on a local network, it is being accessed through the internet. Therefore there is no internal monitoring software that could be causing this. I am using Google Chrome 24 Beta for Mac.

Comment: How do you open a new tab? Chances are they're checking referrers and when it sees you don't have one or you're originating from a page and landing on another that isn't in "Sequence" it bounces an error. It can also use a session variable/ip combination that tracks what page you're viewing.

Comment: Do you see this message as soon as you open a new tab or after performing some action in the new tab? Do you see it if you open a tab via the "Open link in new tab" option?

Comment: I see it as soon as I open a new tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is via cookies and ids. Firstly, you are logged in to the site and have a session on there. This is managed using cookies; whenever you visit a page on the site, your browser will send a cookie which normally contains some kind of id. That way the server can identify any request coming from you, is really from you. So, in this case, both your original tab and your new tab will send the same cookie.

Secondly, it can also add another, different id (call it the page id), to any link or form you submit on the site. So a form on a page might contain the id 1234, and any links will also contain that id. Each new page you visit might contain a new id. So at any point, the site knows that next request from your browser (identified by the cookies) should also contain this other id. If you navigate around the site in a normal way, clicking on links, submitting forms, this will be true and all will be good.

Cases when your next request would NOT submit the expected, second id are:

1. you hit the back button (you would be sending an old page id)
2. you open a new tab (this depends on the browser, but if it opens the
   same page you are already on in the original tab, it would be sending the current page
   id, not the next page id, which the server expects)

Either way, you send a request with a page id the server doesn't expect and it can make a best guess as to what you did.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge - Chrome shares sessions/cookies between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

They track your mouse cursor movement while visiting their website. It's a great way to get the attention of a visitor. They put some query programmatically when you move your mouse and when you wish to close.

It's good UX.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I know the technique you're referring to, but for one I'm not sure this is good UX--one of the biggest annoyances I have is when I move the mouse outside of the window and get a giant subscribe offer or "BUT WAIT" to try to bait me to stay on the website. That's beside the point, though--more relevant to this post, how does the site detect a tab that was opened using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Another way the site may know that you have another tab open is through broadcasting channels. To put it simply, broadcasting channels are a means for windows, tabs, etc; to communicate (correct me if I am wrong). Here is a simple implementation:

```
//Channel to post and receive messages from
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("Check-tabs");

//On message receive
bc.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data === `First tab?`) {

    //Post that there is already a tab open
    bc.postMessage(`Tab already open`);
  }

  //Check if a tab is open
  if (event.data === `Tab already open`) {
    alert(`Another tab is already open.`);
  }

//Posts message to check whether another tab is open
bc.postMessage(`First tab?`);
```