# How to detect the new tab of browser in .net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my website, i want to check that whether the user has opened the homepage of my website in same tab again or in the new tab?
Is there any solution to check that?

Comment: What do you mean "in the same tab again?" Are you trying to check whether he loaded the page fresh, or if he just reloaded the page? That is possible...

Comment: @JasCav, How do we differentiate load fresh && reload in server side? Other than having a hidden field in the page value set to `loaded` and checking it in Request collection? :)

Comment: Browsers don't maintain a constant connection to web servers, so it's not possible to *reliably* determine if a user has a web page open in more than one window.

Comment: [This][1] post might help you! Please check.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455304/how-does-this-site-know-that-i-am-opening-another-tab

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is by checking to see if your current tab or window has any history...

```
if (history.length > 1) {
    // you're in an old tab
} else {
    // you're in a new tab
}
```

This is in Javascript, not server-side, but I don't see how you'd be able to detect anything like this in server-side code.

Comment: I haven't used Firefox in a while, but it failed to preserve the history when opening a link on a new tab (Ctrl / Scroll-click).

Comment: @CodeCaster That's the whole point.  A new tab would only have 1 entry in the history.  Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Well Chrome for example _does_ copy the history of the tab you're coming from, but also not in all cases: Ctrl/Scroll-click a link and the history is cleared, but Ctrl/Scroll-click the Back button and your history get copied.

Comment: @CodeCaster No it doesn't.  If you're opening a link in a new tab then there is no history.  Try it on this page, using Chrome.  I just did :)

Comment: but if the user is already using the tab for another websites, then that will have the history. then what to do?

Comment: This will tell you if the user has gone to the home page in an existing tab, or a new tab.